# After deleting CoreDataBooks.sqlite from the Resources folder, how does it keep being generated?

Tags: ios, core-data

If I delete CoreDataBooks.sqlite from the IPhone Simulator and from the Resources folder, how come does it keep being generated in the Iphone Simulator with all the books data again? I was obviously expecting an empty CoreDataBooks.sqlite to be created on launch.

What am I missing here?

Note: This question refers to the Apple sample project called "*CoreDataBooks*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that the `CoreDataBooks.sqlite` file is still in your build output. Even if you remove the file from your source tree, and remove the app from the simulator, next time you run the app it will be installed from your build output.

Try opening the Product menu, press Option and select ***Clean Build Folder...***. This should remove any previously generated build output, and then you can rebuild the app without the `CoreDataBooks.sqlite` file.

Comment: Thank you. That did end the question.

Comment: Then mark the answer as accepted so that others in future can quickly see that it helps. :-)